# how to create required fields validation in firebase

Tags: firebase, firebase-security

My required field validation rule seems to work in the dashboard rules simulator but I get permission denied when I try it out for real.  Did I set it up correctly?  (.msg is the message text)

```
{
    "rules": {
      "messages":{
        ".read": "auth.uid !== null",
        ".write": "auth.uid !== null",
        ".validate": "newData.child('msg').exists()",
        "uid": {
          ".validate": "auth.uid === newData.val()"
        }
      }
    }
}
```

I've also alternatively tried this syntax in the .validate

```
".validate": "newData.hasChildren(['msg','uid','uname'])"
```

And this also throws a permission denied error for me.

Here's the ios code

```
   func sendMessage(text: String!) {
        // *** STEP 3: ADD A MESSAGE TO FIREBASE
        messagesRef.childByAutoId().setValue([
            "msg":text,
            "uname":self.senderDisplayName,
            "uid":self.senderId
            ])
    }
```

Comment: ok so I figured out that I need to add a dynamic node and it works, e.g. $comment_id:{.validation:...}

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I just needed to add the dynamic message id into the json

```
{
    "rules": {
      "messages":{
        ".read": "auth.uid !== null",
        ".write": "auth.uid !== null",
       "$message_id":{
           ".validate": "newData.child('msg').exists()",
           "uid": {
             ".validate": "auth.uid === newData.val()"
           }
        }
      }
    }
}
```